# An object's child object is null when passed in argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following object structure:

```
class Facts {
 string name;
 string color;
 //other stuff
}
class Fruit {
  Facts Facts {get; set;}
}
class Apple : Fruit {
  Facts Facts {get; set;}
}
class Orange : Fruit {
  Facts Facts {get; set;}
}
```

Now, this is an ASP.NET MVC application, so I'm sending back an `Apple` object to my controller action method. In my action method, I'm calling a helper method and passing the `Apple` as an argument:

my helper method:

```
public void doSomething(Fruit fruit) {
  //do something with *fruit.Facts*
}
```

The problem is, my fruit object is being passed, but the Facts object inside is coming back as null. It's not null in the controller, but when I pass it to this helper method its null... and I don't understand why?

Does this have something to do with the controller passing objects to other methods as parameters or something? I know you can't pass a controller action method an object as a parameter in some instances. Is this related somehow?

Comment: *"why visual studio, y u do dis?*" Visual studio is a code editor, it didn't do it, you did. You are passing a `Fruit` which only knows about the types **it** contains, since, as Jon said, you are having 2 properties named "fruit", you are filling out the derived property but leaving the base property null. You should define the base class as abstract as well as the property.

Comment: @RonBeyer i was just kidding.. about the visual studio thing. Thank you for the clarification however

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you've got two entirely independent properties called `Facts` for an `Apple`. That's a really bad idea - it makes this sort of thing really confusing. The compiler is using whichever one it has access to, based on the compile-time type of the expression you're using.

You should already be getting a warning about this - don't ignore warnings! Here's a short but complete program demonstrating the problem:

```
using System;

class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Apple : Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var apple = new Apple { Name = "AppleName" };
        Fruit fruit = apple;
        Console.WriteLine(fruit.Name); // Nothing!
        fruit.Name = "FruitName";
        Console.WriteLine(((Fruit) apple).Name); // FruitName
        Console.WriteLine(((Apple) fruit).Name); // AppleName
    }
}
```

One object, two names... depending on how you "view" the object.

Just get rid of the declarations of the `Facts` properties in `Apple` and `Orange`.

Comment: I can't do that... they're mapped to my database, but the parent object "Fruit" is not mapped to the database. Is there an alternative method or will the children keep that property mapped to the database even if its not explicitly declared in the child classes?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad: I don't see why "they're mapped to my database" means you can't have a sensible class structure. Do you actually *want* two `Facts` properties per object? I doubt it. It doesn't help that you haven't told us *anything* about the database mapping...

Comment: @JonSkeet do you think that `Fruit` should be marked `abstract` in this case since you wouldn't create a `Fruit` object, but only the derived objects? I think that would solve a lot here...

Comment: @RonBeyer: Maybe. It's hard to tell with so little context. I've explained what I *can* explain in the answer - i.e. why you're seeing what you're seeing. Whatever else you do, I would *strongly* advise changing your classes so that you don't hide properties like this.

Comment: @JonSkeet will it be any different if Facts is not a simple type? May be the derived classes need to override its definition say polymorphic? Just a thought

Comment: @JuliusA: Using a virtual property would mean there's only one *property*, but still two underlying fields, which still doesn't seem terribly useful. Given that they're automatically implemented properties, I can't see why `Apple` needs to redeclare the property anyway.